# When using d3.js, where is the destination for the data source?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm looking at this example here for a d3.js chart:

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8952219

Inside the example, the code that represents the data source is as follows:

```
d3.csv("bar-data.csv", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });
```

It appears to point at the bar-data.csv file.

If I were to replicate this example locally, am I suppose to list the .csv file in the same directory as the index.html page?

Also, could I theoretically plug in a URL instead of the 'bar-data.csv' to point to an external data source?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/CSV.md:

> `d3.csv(url[[, accessor], callback])`
>
> Issues an HTTP GET request for the comma-separated values (CSV) file at the specified url. The file contents are assumed to be RFC4180-compliant. The mime type of the request will be "text/csv".

Therefore `bar-data.csv` is just a relative path and assumes the file to be in the same directory as the browser execution context (ie. what's in your address bar).